# Quartz/Cocoa gradient fill with interpolation in a linear color space?

Tags: macos, cocoa, graphics

Below are two gradients.

In Gradient A, colors were interpolated from Red to Green in a linear color space. i.e. 'gamma-correct'.

Gradient B was drawn on macOS in objective-C using an NSGradient. macOS appears to interpolate the colors of the gradient in the screen-color-space (sRGB or similar). The problem with this gradient is that the color at the midpoint is dark and 'muddy'.

[image: color interpolation]

On macOS, using Quartz or Cocoa to draw a gradient between two colors, can one specify in what color-space the gradient is calculated, to achieve more even brightness across the image, like 'gradient A'?

(the application is a cross-platform drawing framework, where it's desirable that colors render consistently accross Windows, macOS, and IOS).

Comment: See [the documentation of NSGradient]), find "colorspace". Have you tried `init(colors:atLocations:colorSpace:)`?

Comment: Ah, specifying colorSpace:genericRGBColorSpace does change the gradient.
The result is something between the two gradients pictured, but definitely an improvement. want to answer the question officially?

Answer (score 0):

To render a gradient which interpolates colors in a linear color-space use the 'cgColorSpaceGenericRGBLinear' color-space.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGBLinear);
NSColorSpace* nsColorSpace = [[NSColorSpace alloc] initWithCGColorSpace:colorSpace];

gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithColors:colors atLocations: locations2.data() colorSpace: nsColorSpace];
```

[image: macOS gradient fixed]